# Configure application pools with the default settings using AppCmd.exe

Tags: iis-7

I am working on a build script and I need to reconfigure an application pool with the default settings hopefully using AppCmd.exe. Could you point me to the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of settings by using this...

```
appcmd list apppool "test" /text:*
```

You can check https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732992%28v=ws.10%29.aspx for more information.